# ZOH following a step function

Tags: control-theory

Does it make any sense if you put zero order hold after a step input (at any sampling period). I think ZOH does exact reconstruction of a step function regardless of the sampling period.

In the following problem the input is a step function and the ZOH comes after this. Shouldn't we get the same response as if it were a purely continuous (not sampled at all) system?
[discretize a function using $z$-transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438311/discretize-a-function-using-z-transform/1921241#1921241)

Answer (score 0):

$h_{\text{ZOH}}(t)=\text{rect}(\frac{t-T/2}{T})$ is used for reconstruction of a sampled signal which is represented by $s[n]=\sum s(nT)\delta(t-nT)$.
 So the output is $h*s=\sum s(nT)\text{rect}(\frac{t-T/2-nT}{T})$.

Now if we follow two appropriately scaled and delayed $h_{ZOH}$ by a $u(t)$, the result is $$(h_{ZOH}(t+T/2)-h_{ZOH}(t-T/2))*u(t)=\text{tri}(\frac{t}{T})=h_{FOH}(t)$$

The overall result is a first-order hold filter

Comment: Dear msm, Would you say more to show me the inconsistency in the following straightforward logic. If you sample a step function at time $t_1$ and keep it at its value until the next sampling time $t_1+T$, what you have done does not modify the step function it stays as it is.

Comment: I didn't realize you have given a link to another question. Generally, ZOH does not perfectly reconstruct the signal. Perfect reconstruction is only possible by infinite sinc functions. So there will be distortion (if you mean it).